# Dropdown menu can't show in IE

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu using css, I open with firefox that look ok. But when I try to open using IE 9, dropdown menu show, but it look transparent and content not show.

Here it's after I checked in my CSS, if I remove this code, in IE ok. But I want to keep this code. So how can I do that ?

[image]

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter:progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(
    startColorstr='#00a1bc',
    endColorstr='#008ba2',
    GradientType=0);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Comment: if you take out the `filter` from your CSS does it work?

Comment: are you using CSS3PIE? This will interfere with the declared filter.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell for sure because I'd need to see more of the code, but looking at the image it looks like it could possibly be a problem with the z-index. It looks to me as though the table looking content is sitting on top of the dropdown, thus blocking anything within it.

If you are using the position property on the dropdown and also the content that appears to be above/behind it, then make sure that the dropdown has a higher z-index than that of the other content.

Answer (score -1):

Please try adding an -ms- vendor prefix for the gradient.